# Build ExtJS app in Laravel structure

Tags: laravel, extjs, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, extjs5

I want to build ExtJS (5.1.0) app in Laravel structure.

---

+project

++public

+++js

++++admin (built extjs app)

++++libs

+++++ext-5.1.0 (framework)

+project

++resources

+++views

++++admin
******index.blade.php

---

I ran CMD command (in project/public/js path):

```
sencha -sdk libs\ext-5.1.0 generate app MyApp admin
```

In app.json i set:

```
"indexHtmlPath": "../../../resources/views/admin/index.blade.php"
```

In index.blade.php i set:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="/js/admin/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

After build the generated bootstrap.js contains:

```
Ext.manifest = Ext.manifest || "../../../public/js/admin/bootstrap.json";
```

And bootstrap.json has set all paths with "public" expression.
For example:

```
"Ext.app":"../../../public/js/admin/ext/packages/sencha-core/src/app"

"Ext.browser":"../../../public/js/admin/ext/packages/sencha-core/src/env/Browser.js"
```

Browser is looking for a 
`myapp.localhost/public/js/admin/bootstrap.js` file, but real path is `myapp.localhost/js/admin/bootstrap.js` (without "public").

I have no idea how to build the app correctly.

Comment: Anyone? It's very frustrating issue while building refresh app.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same too...can't understand how to put Laravel 5.3 and ExtJS 6 together.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I haven't tried this link, but he seems to get it to work: http://www.extjstips.com/2015/11/03/build-an-extjs-and-laravel-application-part-1/
Github: https://github.com/mikerh/ext-app

Comment: Maybe you can work on a restful API with Laravel and consume the services and data with an extjs app